# Copy parameter sets from a CmdLet to new CmdLet

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-cmdlet

I want to create a replacement function for `Write-Error`. To do this, it must support the same parameter sets as the original CmdLet.

I can see what parameter sets `Write-Error` supports by using

```
Get-Help Write-Error
```

or online on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-EN/library/dd315265.aspx)

> NAME
>       Write-Error
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       Writes an object to the error stream.
>
> SYNTAX
>       Write-Error [-Message]  [-Category ] [-CategoryActivity ] [-CategoryReason ]
>        [-CategoryTargetName ] [-CategoryTargetType ] [-ErrorId ] [-RecommendedAction ] [-
>       TargetObject ] []
>
> ```
> Write-Error [-Category <ErrorCategory>] [-CategoryActivity <String>] [-CategoryReason <String>] [-CategoryTargetNam
> e <String>] [-CategoryTargetType <String>] [-ErrorId <String>] [-Message <String>] [-RecommendedAction <String>] [-
> TargetObject <Object>] -Exception <Exception> [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Write-Error [-CategoryActivity <String>] [-CategoryReason <String>] [-CategoryTargetName <String>] [-CategoryTarget
> Type <String>] [-RecommendedAction <String>] -ErrorRecord <ErrorRecord> [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

But how can i easily create a new PowerShell script CmdLet that uses the exact same parameter sets (including required parameters and default values)?

Comment: [cmdletbinding()] will get you some of that, not all though.  You will have to write a cmdlet in C# for the functionality you are wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for proxy function. You can create proxy function using command metadata:

```
$command = Get-Command Write-Error
$proxy = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($command)
```

Some links that should help explain it:

- [Scripting Guys blog (post by PS MVP Shay Levy)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx)
- [PowerShell Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx)

There is also PowerShell module ([pspx](https://pspx.codeplex.com)) that could get you started.